# Why does beer dehydrate you?

Tags: drinking, water

It's often recommended that you drink water before and during a heavy drinking session.  Why is it that, despite being mostly water, beer dehydrates you?

Comment: Crap, I think you're right.  Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: A bit of a shame, since I actually like your question better.

Answer (score 13):

Well, this question might get closed as a duplicate, but I'm going to answer it anyway, and try to answer it better. IMO, the suggested duplicate answers a *different* question, only answering the hydration question too, by side-effect. Personally, I like *this* question paired with *that* answer, better than *that* question.

#### tl;dr — Alcohol is a diuretic (defined: *a substance that promotes the production of urine*), causing you to expel more water than the body would normally expel.

That much has been shown conclusively.

> If sufficient alcohol is ingested, the diuresis occurs at the expense of all cellular components, and dehydration ensues.

<sup>[Roberts, K. E. Mechanism of Dehydration Following Alcohol Ingestion. 1963. [Abstract (HTML)]](http://archinte.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=568848)</sup>

As far back as the 1930s, researchers were trying to understand whether alcohol—the substance itself—is a diuretic, or indirectly induces chemicals which are diuretic (or which inhibit antidiuretics) or triggers cortical functions that cause diuresis.

> [Most] writers either state categorically or imply that alcohol per se has no diuretic action. In 1932, however, from a comparison of the diuretic effects of a given volume of water, with and without alcohol, [...] Murray concluded that alcohol itself was exerting a diuretic action. [...] The diuretic action of alcohol has now been demonstrated on five other subjects, and its mode of action investigated [...]

<sup>[Eggleton, M. G. The Diuretic Action of Alcohol in Man. 1941. [Full Paper (PDF)]](http://jp.physoc.org/content/101/2/172.full.pdf)</sup>

The first paper (1963) actually confirmed that **alcohol—yes, ethanol itself—inhibits antidiuretic hormones, causing diuresis, causing dehydration.** (Caffeine does this too, by the way.)

So, yeah. That's how that happens.

---

Unrelated, but I found this interesting in the second paper...

> It [the diuresis] is initiated by the *increase* in blood-alcohol concentration and fails to be maintained if this concentration is kept steady, even at high levels [...] The diuretic response to alcohol differs markedly in one respect from that of the cerebral cortex. The latter is most affected by the *rate* of increase in blood-alcohol concentration: the greater this rate of increase, the greater the disturbance of function at any absolute concentration. The diuretic response, on the other hand, is dependent mainly on the *duration* of increasing blood-alcohol concentration and not on the rate of increase (Tables 6, 7). The naturally slow absorber, therefore, tends to give a larger diuretic response than the rapid absorber.

The slower you get drunk, the more dehydrated you'll be!